# Narrow the width of some characters without changing the font

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to narrow the look of only particular characters such as a, b, and c (Unicode code points #x61 through #x63) to 1/3 or something in width, without changing the font? If so, how? I know that you can change font for some particular Unicode code point ranges, and there's a type of font called condensed font, but I'd like to keep the font as is. The reason I don't like to change font is that I'm thinking of applying this to some fonts that there's not really an exact narrow-width equivalent for, like the color emoji font by Apple.

Comment: When you say “without changing the font”, you mean without switching to a different font that has a different width, right? One way might be to change the font, as in, make a copy of the font file and edit it to change the width of some characters, to effectively produce a condensed font.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles , I'll try that method when I get enough time to do that. I wish there was some easy way to achieve this for bunch of glyphs, but still, thanks!